# All fields are showing in one column when exporting data to csv using php

Tags: php, excel, export-to-excel

I have written a php code in wordpress to export an array to csv file. But all fields show in one column.

```
        $delimiter = ",";
        $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w'); 
        fprintf($f, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
        $fields = array('تصویر پروفایل', 'مدرک تحصیلی' , 'کد ملی' , 'نام و نام خانوادگی' , 'شماره عضویت'); 
        fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter);
        foreach($output as $row){
            $lineData = array($row['شماره عضویت'], $row['نام و نام خانوادگی'], $row['کدملی'], $row['مدرک تحصیلی'], $row['تصویر پروفایل']);
            fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter);
        }
        fseek($f, 0);
        $fileName = "codexworld_export_data-" . date('Ymd') . ".csv";
        header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
        header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fileName\"");
        fpassthru($f);
        exit;
```

[image]

Comment: Please change tags from `php` and `wordpress` to `excel`, because the error is clearly in excel. You need to split column one on the `,`, to see multiple columns. (see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7 )

Comment: i think you can change fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter); to fputcsv($f, $row);

Comment: Change your `php` tag to `wordpress`, because the question belongs to WordPress.